# in which of X or Y

Tags: grammar

> You know **in which of Sydney or New York** the woman called Noemia
> lives.

Is this the proper way to say this? It sounds a bit weird, but I am wondering if you can use that phrase in the way I am using it.

Comment: It is a clumsy construction, I suggest "You know whether Noemia lives in Sydney or New York," but even that seems strange. "You know where Noemia lives."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very odd thing to say, and an odd way to express it. It would be much more natural to say

> You know whether it's in Sydney or New York that [the woman called] Noemia lives.

or, more simply

> You know whether Noemia lives in Sydney or New York.

Answer (score -2):

**No the phrase is,** as written extremely **ambiguous.**

It states you know where the woman lives, however

It is not a question

It is not a comparison

It is not a statement.

---

the use of  "in which of Sydney or New York" in it's self is awkward phrase. However it is possible to use it, although it's use would be non standard English.

> In which of, Sydney or New York, would you find Bondi Beach?

Comment: Your example sentence is not grammatically correct. It is an example of a [comma splice.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) Inserting "..the following" before the first comma might make it acceptable, but it is still awkwardly phrased compared to a sentence like **Is Bondi Beach in Sydney or New York?**

Comment: @randomhead I would not argue the facts of what you are saying. It is awkwardly phrased and I would never use it. However I am pretty certain that I have heard questions phrased in a similar way to this on quiz shows. Which is possibly where the PO also saw or heard it. **But yes it is a sentence I would never use** and yes *In which of **these**, Sydney or New York, would you find Bondi Beach?* might sound better but the OP post was *"in which of Sydney or New York"*